# Query for execution time scheduled task per database

Tags: sql-server, backup

My database backup task that runs every day is taking a long time to complete. It whent from 45 minutes to 3 hours in 2 weeks time. Is there a way i can see which database is problematic? The history doesnt give me much information to go on.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to take advantage of the script provided in [How to find out how long a SQL Server backup took](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1747/how-to-find-out-how-long-a-sql-server-backup-took/)

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname
SET @dbname = NULL --set this to be whatever dbname you want
SELECT bup.user_name AS [User],
 bup.database_name AS [Database],
 bup.server_name AS [Server],
 bup.backup_start_date AS [Backup Started],
 bup.backup_finish_date AS [Backup Finished]
 ,CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))/3600 AS varchar) + ' hours, ' 
 + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))/60 AS varchar)+ ' minutes, '
 + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))%60 AS varchar)+ ' seconds'
 AS [Total Time]
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bup
WHERE bup.backup_set_id IN
  (SELECT MAX(backup_set_id) FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
  WHERE database_name = ISNULL(@dbname, database_name) --if no dbname, then return all
  AND type = 'D' --only interested in the time of last full backup
  GROUP BY database_name) 
/* COMMENT THE NEXT LINE IF YOU WANT ALL BACKUP HISTORY */
AND bup.database_name IN (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases)
ORDER BY bup.database_name
```

If you want to get a list of all backups and not just the most recent you can issue the following:

```
DECLARE @dbname sysname
SET @dbname = NULL --set this to be whatever dbname you want
SELECT bup.user_name AS [User],
 bup.database_name AS [Database],
 bup.server_name AS [Server],
 bup.backup_start_date AS [Backup Started],
 bup.backup_finish_date AS [Backup Finished]
 ,CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))/3600 AS varchar) + ' hours, ' 
 + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))/60 AS varchar)+ ' minutes, '
 + CAST((CAST(DATEDIFF(s, bup.backup_start_date, bup.backup_finish_date) AS int))%60 AS varchar)+ ' seconds'
 AS [Total Time]
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bup
/* COMMENT THE NEXT LINE IF YOU WANT ALL BACKUP HISTORY */
WHERE bup.database_name IN (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases)
ORDER BY bup.database_name
```

Comment: ORDER BY bup.database_name, bup.backup_start_date to better see the "progress" in time :)